# Como mostrar o maior número digitado, usando funções?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void maior(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int cont, maior1;
    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;
        maior(maior1,cont);
    }while (cont != -1);
    cout << "o maior numero e: " << maior1
    return 0;
}

void maior(int a, int b){
    b=0;
    if (a>b){
        a=b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que a forma mais simples é guardar o maior número entrado e, após cada entrada, verificar se o número entrado é maior que esse, se sim passa a ser o entrado o maior.

```
int main(void) {
    int cont, maior = 0;
    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;
        //Se o valor entrado for maior que o ultimo passa ele a ser o maior
        if(cont > maior)maior = cont;
    }while (cont != -1);
    cout << "o maior numero e: " << maior;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/DoidrM)

Se quiser pode utilizar uma função para fazer a comparação e retornar o maior dos dois números:

```
int getMaior(int a, int b);
int main(void) {
    int cont, maior = 0;
    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;
        //Se o valor entrado for maior que o ultimo passa ele a ser o maior
        maior = getMaior(cont, maior);
    }while (cont != -1);
    cout << "o maior numero e: " << maior;
    return 0;
}

int getMaior(int a, int b){
    if (a>b) return a;
    return b;
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/yGNukG)

Comment: Só que obrigatoriamente eu tenho que usar funções.

Comment: Fácil, vou editar a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cont, maior1 = 0;
    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;
        maior1 = maior(cont,maior1);
    }while (cont != -1);
    cout << "o maior numero e: " << maior1
    return 0;
}

int maior(int a, int b){
//    b=0;  pq zerou um parâmetro inserido?
    if (a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Não entendi o motivo de usar uma function, deve ser coisa de curso. Mas... está aí.

Comment: Não entendi porque não usar. Na verdade ela dá melhor semântica e canonicalidade. É verdade que em coisas simples assim a necessidade é questionável. Mas porque não se acostumar fazer as coisas de forma organizada como se o sistema fosse real e complexo?

Comment: Muito bem citado. Mas, como falaste, este é um caso de "coisas simples". Por este motivo sinalizei a necessidade de tal função.
E, sim, utilizar métodos/functions é essencial para uma melhor organização de código.

Comment: É bem verdade que eu usaria uma função pronta neste caso :) Mas é exercício...

Comment: Haha. Sim, tive de fazer muito disso quando iniciei.